# Mix Linq queries with native SQL queries

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I'm using mysql backend with Entity Framework 6.1.3, MySql.Data.Entity 6.9.9 and Visual Studio 2015. 
There is a bug in MySql.Data.Entity with "group by" clause with generate "unknown column" error. The [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46742) was reported in mysql. But still not fixed.

So I'm trying to mix Linq query with SQL query, Something like,

```
from ansId in ctx.Database.SqlQuery<int>("select UserId from answers where QuestionId = 1 group by UserId")
from uss in ctx.UserSurveys.Where(u => u.UserID == ansId)
select new { ... }
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: No it's not possible.

Comment: Thanks. I found a workaround. I used database view to group table.