# EF 6.x, LINQ-to-SQL and raw SQL clauses

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

The overarching question here is: *how can incorporate XML column queries into a LINQ-to-SQL expression, such that it's correctly translated to SQL (and not just performed in memory) via `IQueryable` with EF 6.x?*

---

Is there a way to incorporate a raw SQL query expression in a LINQ-to-SQL query (in this case, using EF 6.x backed by SQL Server)

For example:

```
var activeSince2016 = dbContext.Users
    .Where(u => u.IsActive)
    .WhereSql("[CreatedAt] > '2016-01-01'")
    // ...
    .ToList();
```

The above example is contrived, however, my reason for asking is due to EF's lack of support for XML types (and XPath queries against them).

A more accurate example query would be:

```
var activeAndMillennial = dbContext.Users
    .Where(u => u.IsActive)
    .WhereSql("[UserXmlInfo].value('/Info/Age', 'int') < 25")
    // ...
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think its possible to do that, reference from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39897220/6741868).

Comment: First, Linq-to-Sql and Entity framework are two entirely different, and incompatible technologies.  I think you mean Linq to Entities.  Second, you might want to look into Entity Sql Language (or esql).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/entity-sql-language

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch That *is* what I meant; late night question asking has it's pitfalls. And thanks for the link, is this analogous to NHibernate's HQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it appears one can do hte reverse (sort of) of my question, using [`FromSql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsql?view=efcore-2.1) in EF Core 2.1 (*see also the page on [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)*)

```
var searchTerm = ".NET";

var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSql($"SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchBlogs({searchTerm})")
    .Include(b => b.Posts)
    .ToList();
```

While it's still not possible (*it seems*) to inject raw SQL expressions between LINQ calls, this may still be helpful.<sup>§</sup>

<sub>§ I personally abandoned this a long time ago.</sub>